# Проблемы с git-push

Tags: git, git-push

Занимаемся внедрением git в разработку на предприятии.
Работаем в ОС Ubuntu. У нас есть личные компьютеры и сетевое хранилище данных. Все личные компьютеры подключены к хранилищу.

Необходимо: 1) создать удаленный репозиторий на хранилище; 2)создать локальные репозитории на каждом персональном компьютере.

Мы делаем следующее:

1. создаем удаленный пустой репозиторий командой «git init --bare»;
2. создаем локальный репозиторий в папке нашего проекта командой «git init»;
3. подключаем удаленный репозиторий к локальному с помощью команды «git remote add 'Name' 'URL'»;
4. создаем первый коммит в локальном репозитории с помощью команд «git add .» и «git commit -m "Сообщение"»;
5. отправляем первый локальный коммит в удаленный репозиторий с помощью команды «git push -u 'Name' master».

При отправке первого коммита в удаленный репозиторий возникают следующие ошибки:

1. remote: fatal: write error: Неподдерживаемая операция;
2. error: сбой при внешней распаковке index-pack abnormal exit;
3. error: не удалось отправить некоторые ссылки в 'адрес удаленного репозитория'.
   Перечисленные ошибки показаны в прилагаемом скриншоте.

При создании тестовых удаленных и локальных репозиториев с одним пробным текстовым файлом описанный выше алгоритм работает нормально, но не работает с папкой проекта, которая содержит около 500+ файлов (включая файлы с кодом).

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с этой проблемой.

[image: ошибке при пуше проекта]

Comment: По какому протоколу подключён remote?

Comment: И вообще, посему бы не взять что-нибудь готовое? Gitlab, github, gitea….

Comment: перепутали пункт 3 и 4. сначала нужно `commit` потом `remote add`

Comment: По поводу протокола затрудняюсь ответить. А как можно запросить тип протокола?
Судя по документации git, у нас обычный локальный протокол, поскольку удаленным репозиторием является общее сетевое хранилище.

Готовые решения не подходят в связи со спецификой работы.

Comment: Специфика работы мешает использовать сайт GitLab, или запрещает развернуть GitLab на сервере организации, во внутренней сети?

Comment: @AlexGlebe и в нашем и в Вашем варианте последовательности действий выдает одни и те же ошибки.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов, да, специфика не позволяет использовать сайт. Из имеющегося есть только сетевое хранилище. Возможно ли на нем развернуть GitLab?

Comment: Ну покажите что вы спрятали словом URL

Comment: @AlexeyTen, адрес сетевого хранилища: /run/user/1000/gvfs/afp-volume:host=sirv.local,user=sirv,volume=sirv/TestURL. Где TestURL это папка с удаленным репозиторием.

Comment: @Noulzz, я не специалист, но у нас развернут именно GitLab на внутреннем сервере фирмы

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов доступа к развертыванию доп систем на сервере, к сожалению, нет. Только общее хранилище.

Comment: Т,е. с точки зрения git-а это локальная папка. Скорее всего просто не хватает прав на запись.

Comment: В целом дурацкая идея, нужно не изобретать велосипед, а сделать нормальный сервер.

Comment: @AlexeyTen права на запись есть у всех. Приведенный выше алгоритм срабатывает, например, с простыми текстовыми файлами - обеспечивается полноценная работа в системе Git. Проблема возникает при обработке проекта на 500+ файлов. Ограничений на запись ни по количеству, ни по объему файлов не установлено.

Comment: судя по `gvfs/afp-volume`, вы используете afp over fuse. проблемы могут быть связаны именно с этим. вторая гипотеза — я так понял, что в команде remote в качестве url вы указываете вот этот путь: `/run/user/1000/gvfs/afp-volume:host=sirv.local,user=sirv,volume=sirv/TestURL`. я бы предложил сделать симлинк и указывать в команде remote именно его. что-то типа: `$ ln -s /run/user/1000/gvfs/afp-volume:host=sirv.local,user=sirv,volume=sirv/TestURL ~/TestURL` и `$ git remote add имя ~/TestURL`.

Comment: @AlexeyTen `В целом дурацкая идея, нужно не изобретать велосипед, а сделать нормальный сервер.` — если транспорт работает нормально, то вообще-то нет никакой разницы — какой именно это будет транспорт: ssh/http/прямой файловый доступ. здесь похоже как раз на проблемы в работе самого транспорта (файловый доступ, но не прямой, а по протоколу afp over fuse). но если у автора вопроса нет возможности запустить sshd/httpd на машине, где они планируют держать git-хранилище, то ваш совет выходит ещё менее подходящим.

Comment: что бы я ещё рекомендовал опробовать: попробовать избавиться от использования протокола afp (в основном из-за необходимости использовать при этом fuse). вполне возможно, что тот сервер, с которого вы монтируете каталоги, поддерживает и другие протоколы файлового обмена.

Comment: « Занимаемся внедрением git в разработку на предприятии.» обычно под это выделяются бюджеты и какие-никакие ресурсы

Comment: Присоединяюсь к комментариям @aleksandrbarakin, попробуйте что-нибудь типа sshfs. Она точно работает с Git.